Point features not rotating when map view is rotated using QGIS
I have a point layer in QGIS with features sorted after a specified value. Meaning, my features are categorized and are symbol layers of type "Font Marker". Now, since they are street labels they also have to be put parallel to the orientation of the street. For that reason I added a parameter to the features called "angle" where the orientation of each feature is stored in degrees between 0-360 (I think). The problem is that I gave these values once manually and for any reason negative values were also accepted.
Well, the main problem is that these values were set when the map was rotated 62° and now when I want to set the map view rotation to 0° (a must for georeferenced PDFs) all my features are not along the streets.
How can I make the rotation of my features be fixed to the rotation of the map?

I found a solution for my problem.
At the begining it looked like this.

Rotation of the map 62° and the labels of the streets are in the correct direction.

Rotation of the map 0° and the labels dont fit with the streets
The solution was to open the symbol selector and edit the properties for the rotation.

In my case the rotation of my labels was stored in a field called "winkel". Each symbol has its rotation value stored there.

What I did to solve my problem was to writte the next expression.
"winkel" -  @map_rotation - 62

It allowed the labels to go back the 62° when the map view is at 0° as well.
Just to give you a little bit of context why I needed it is that georeferenced PDFs can only be created if the map view is at 0°.
I hope I could be of help if some else was also struggling creating geo PDFs

